# Receiving data from website when app is closed

Tags: android

I have an app that lets user log in to the website and it displays data received from that same website. I am trying to implement notifications that are sent when a certain "Expiration Date" is close to current local date

Here is a scenario:

---

User logs in -> HTTP Request is sent; Response received; -> Current Data displayed -> A person closes app, yet doesn't log out

Expiration date that was received from the server at the time of login was - 07.31.2020

Now, I want to show user a notification when difference between Current Date and Expiration Date is < 5 days, in order to do that, I need to do the following:

1. Send HTTP Request to webpage
2. Receive response and extra data from it
3. Calculate difference in days between Current Local Date & Expiration Date that was just received (X)
4. If day difference < 5 days -> Send notification of "Parameter expires in X days"

I am able to do Requests, Calculations and etc, yet only when I working with the app myself in foreground

**Main issue lies with the fact that I need to do all of this even when app is in Background or Closed, basically even when user doesn't interact with the app, yet has logged in and hasn't logged out and all of this has to be done daily or at least on a scheduled basis.**

Comment: Have you tried WorkManager?

Comment: @KashishSharma I have looked into it, but I wasn't sure if WorkManager would suit my needs, but I will definitely study it more closely

Comment: try PeriodicWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might find this:

I tried using Work Manager, however, it didn't really fit my case because I needed 100% guaranteed and time-sensitive execution which WorkManager can't really do.

Therefore I used AlarmManager with the help of which I could guarantee task execution every time.